# METEOR setup : I am getting error

Tags: node.js, ssl, meteor, npm

I have done everything successfully but stuck here (See attachment) and do not know what to do can anybody share their experience.

same error I was facing when installing MEAN stack but set `npm config ssl` false and got success but in case of METEOR, I am unable to find any config setting where can I switch of "SSL" and certificate authentication for METEOR.

[image: Attachment]
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of npm do you have installed?